# Using WM_COPYDATA for sending a String message between Java apps using JNI

Tags: java, c, winapi

I want to send a simple string message between Java applications using `WM_COPYDATA` (Windows' Data Copy IPC mechanism). I am using JNI to write the WinAPI code in C.

At this stage, I just simply print the message out at the receiving application. Currently, it just prints out **null**. I suspect it is because of `lParam` not being initialised. But I don't know how to use `lParam` to extract the data from `COPYDATASTRUCT`.

Any suggested solutions would be much appreciated. As you'll see, I'm new to WinAPI.

I currently have the following code:

**Sending code:**

```
HWND hwnd = 0;
LPCTSTR lpszString = "A message";
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = 1;
cds.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR) * (_tcslen(lpszString) + 1);
cds.lpData = (TCHAR*)lpszString;
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)hwnd, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds);
return 0; // success
```

**Receiving Code:**

```
LPARAM lParam;
COPYDATASTRUCT* pcds = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)lParam;
if (WM_COPYDATA)
{
   LPCTSTR lpszString = (LPCTSTR)(pcds->lpData);
   printf("%s\n", lpszString);
} 
else return -1;
return 0; // success
```

Comment: `if (WM_COPYDATA)` is always true, because that is equivalent to something like `if (100)` or whatever the exact value of `WM_COPYDATA` is. . Did you mean to compare something, e.g. `if (bla.msg == WM_COPYDATA)`?

Comment: You need a [mcve]. You also should stop using TCHAR which is just confusing. Use Unicode.

Comment: Thanks @RudyVelthuis. This is an error on my part. Will correct. I don't need to compare `WM_DATACOPY` with anything. I just simply need to get the string from `COPYDATASTRUCT` using `lParam` but can't really find decent examples of how this is done

Comment: If you don't need to compare, then what is the `if (WM_COPYDATA)` for? Or is this not your real code? If not, how can we find out what the problem really is? If it is, then it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I have removed the if statement and it is my code. I have seen examples on the net where this value is checked. My point is that I don't really know how to go about retrieving the value and whether a check on this is necessary or not.

Comment: If it is the only message you send, then there is no need. If you send several different messages (at different times), then you must check. But `hwnd = 0` is wrong. You must use the `hwnd` of the window that should receive and handle the message. You may want to read MSDN on message handling.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: *"If it is the only message you send, then there is no need."* - This were true if (and only if) you were the **only** sender of messages. This can never be the case, since the system will always send messages (e.g. `WM_CREATE`).

Comment: @IInspectable: I know. But he claims that he doesn't have to check.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: And I claim, that you named the wrong precondition. You are both wrong.

Comment: Ok, you are probably right. I merely meant that `if (WM_COPYDATA)` did not make any sense at all. He should check if the message received is really a `WM_COPYDATA` with that `if`. But ISTM this is all code collected from the interwebs, but not really understood. And I wonder if Java doesn't have its own ways to do IPC, so there is no need to use Windows messaging and hidden windows, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending to a window handle with the value 0. You have to supply a valid window handle and 0 is not.

Some other comments:

- You ostensibly use `TCHAR` but your code can only compile for ANSI. Unless you target Windows 98 don't use `TCHAR`. Use Unicode.
- You should not assume that the data is null terminated when receiving. Make sure you copy no more than `cbSize` bytes. This guards against buffer overruns in case the sender is not who you expect.
- It is customary to check `dwData` as a means to verify that the sender is who you expect.
- Likewise you would normally pass the sender window as `wParam` rather than the recipient.
- `if (WM_COPYDATA)` is pointless. The condition evaluates true at compile time.

Looking at your code it is not at all obvious that you have created any windows. You need a window to receive the message. Perhaps that is at the root of your problem. Since you did not provide an MCVE it is hard to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I haven't created any windows. Am I wrong in assuming that Data Copy can only be used as an IPC mechanism for applications that have windows? I simply need it for console-based Java apps.

Comment: @DylSmith: `SendMessage` takes a `HWND` parameter, that identifies the destination. There is no other means of identifying the destination. Consequently, the destination **must** be a valid window handle. That does not imply, that your process needs a user-visible UI. A [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) is sufficient. The receiver must still have a message loop, because this IPC mechanism relies on message-handling.

Comment: FWIW, C++Builder also uses `TCHAR` and `tchar.h` in newly generated console apps.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. I am using `hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "Class", NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL );` subsequent to reading your link to create a message only window but I keep receiving 'ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS' (error 1407) when I do this. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @DylSmith: The error message implies, that the window class named `Class` cannot be found. The system cannot create window classes it doesn't know. To introduce a window class, call the [RegisterClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586.aspx) API call. This sounds a lot, like you don't know, how to create a Windows application. You should consider reading a book, like Petzold's [Programming Windows®](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's as wrong there as it is everywhere else

Comment: @IInspectable ok so I have created class using `RegisterClass` and created a message-only window using `CreateWindowEx` and it works correctly (as `hwnd` is not 0). On the receiving side, I am using `FindWindowEx` to find the window and this behaves as expected. The problem is that I still cannot retrieve the message. And yes, as a mentioned in my post, I am new to WinAPI

Comment: @DylSmith: You need to create a [mcve], unless you are fine with guessing. I'm guessing, that your target doesn't run a message loop, or fails to filter out the respective message (`WM_COPYDATA`).

Comment: @DylSmith You have moved on to a different problem now. Related I grant you. But now you want us to debug a different program. You asked a specific question. Did I not answer it? If I answered it you should accept the answer and move on. If you have another question please ask it – as another question.